# How do I forward an array value using an if statement comes back false?

Tags: arrays, excel, indexing, match

I am trying to only pull lunch times in an array if they are over an hour long and display the full value of that time.

I've tried to use an if statement to wrap the entire code and increment if false by one. I've been searching forms trying to see what I am doing wrong but not able to find anything. I have one functioning formula that will pull all break times and display time and dates but does not work when I try to use it to find specifics ones.

```
Two cells that are working:
Date it happened: {=IFERROR(INDEX(Time,SMALL(IF(Reason=$K7,ROW(Duration)-MIN(ROW(Duration))+1),COLUMNS($K$7:K7))),"")}
Value of Duration: {=IFERROR(Duration(Time,SMALL(IF(Reason=$K7,ROW(Duration)-MIN(ROW(Duration))+1),COLUMNS($K$7:K7))),"")}

The formula I am trying:
{=IF(INDEX(Duration,SMALL(IF(Reason=$K7,ROW(Duration)-MIN(ROW(Duration))+1),COLUMNS($K$7:K7)))>=TIME(1,0,0),IFERROR(INDEX(Duration,SMALL(IF(Reason=$K7,ROW(Duration)-MIN(ROW(Duration))+1),COLUMNS($K$7:K7))),""),IFERROR(INDEX(Duration,SMALL(IF(Reason=$K7,ROW(Duration)-MIN(ROW(Duration))+1),COLUMNS($K$7:L7))),""))}
```

That formula does ignore the times that are under an hour however it pulls the same data twice. For Example the first duration formula displays the following:

1:11:46 0:59:28 1:11:51 1:10:59

The second one shows:

1:11:46 1:11:51 1:11:51 1:10:59

My ultimate goal is to have it look up a name and then for breaks/lunches but for right now I just want to to look up the lunch times. I would like it to make the output of 1:11:46 1:11:51 1:10:59 . Any thoughts?

Comment: Something I was trying is 
    =IFERROR(INDEX(Duration,SMALL(IF(AND((Reason=$K7),(Duration>TIME(1,0,0))),ROW(Duration)-MIN(ROW(Duration))+1),COLUMNS($K$7:K7))),"") but unfortunatly that did not work either

Comment: =IFERROR(INDEX(Duration,SMALL(IF((Reason=$K7)*(Duration>=TIME(1,0,0)),ROW(Duration)-MIN(ROW(Duration))+1),COLUMNS($K$7:K7))),"")



^ That fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Duration,SMALL(IF((Reason=$K7)*(Duration>=TIME(1,0,0)),ROW(Duration)-MIN(ROW(Duration))+1),COLUMNS($K$7:K7))),"")
```

^ That fixed it